# Import Signing Certificate is Failing

Tags: digital-signature, x509certificate, digital-certificate, makecert

I am attempting to create a certificate with a private key (.pfx) that I can use within my application to create and verify digital signatures. I want to install this certificate into the certificate store (Windows).

I am having issues importing the certificate onto my local machine. The certificate import wizard is always reporting 'The password you entered is incorrect'. This is referring to the password for the private key in the pfx file I have created.

Now I know for a fact that the password is correct, so there must be some other factor in play here.

The script I am using to create the key is with a batch file and contains the following command:

```
makecert -r -pe -n "CN=%1" -b 01/01/2010 -e 01/01/2060 -sky signature %1.cer -sv %1.pvk
pvk2pfx.exe -pvk %1.pvk -spc %1.cer -pfx %1.pfx
```

Does anyone know what could be causing the import wizard to tell me 'The password you entered is incorrect'?

Comment: I trust the computer more than I trust you. The password you enter is incorrect. There may be differences in white space, invisible characters or case.

Comment: Yes, I would think the same. I have tried this with a single character password to try and remove any possibility of me fumbling the password. When you enter the password in the import wizard you can specify 'display password'. I am 100% certain I have specified the password correctly - It still fails.

Comment: For anyone who gets a similar problem: The problem is with the pvk2pfx.exe command. When using this to package a key with a password you need to specify the -pi command line argument with the password of the private key.

Comment: does that mean that you used -pi insted of -po ?

Comment: Oh yes it works Thanks !!!! the solution is to use -pi insted of -po , I think you need to add it as a solution not as comment, to make it clear

Answer (score 7):

As MarkW pointed out, try entering the password into the command line instead of typing into the dialog, eg:

`pvk2pfx -pvk Test.pvk -pi p4sswd -spc Test.cer -pfx Test.pfx -po p4sswd`

Answer (score 1):

If you enter the password in the dialogue using `pvk2pfx.exe` the password will be blank if you try to import the `.pfx` file later. As others have mentioned you can set a password with `-pi`. If you wan't a different password than the private key password you can use `-po`.

pvk2pfx.exe usage instructions:

```
pvk2pfx -pvk <pvk-file> [-pi <pvk-pswd>] -spc <spc-file>
       [-pfx <pfx-file> [-po <pfx-pswd>] [-f]]

    -pvk <pvk-file>  - input PVK file name.
    -spc <spc-file>  - input SPC file name.
    -pfx <pfx-file>  - output PFX file name.
    -pi <pvk-pswd>   - PVK password.
    -po <pfx-pswd>   - PFX password; same as -pi if not given.
    -f               - force overwrite existing PFX file.

    if -pfx option is not given, an export wizard will pop up. in
    this case, options -po and -f are ignored.
```